# Validating user using .pre save

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

My API accepts `users` POSTed as JSON. I would like to validate certain fields only if they are included as part of the JSON object.

For example, a user might look like this:

```
{
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "username" : "testing",
  "name" : "Test User"
}
```

or it might not have a name field:

```
{
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "username" : "testing"
}
```

and I would like to make sure `name` has at least 6 characters if it is an included field.

I'm trying to build the validation process into my model using `.pre` but things aren't quite as I'd expect them.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  id                      : String,
  name                    : String,
  email                   : String,
  username                : String
},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at',updatedAt: 'updated_at' } });

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  console.log(this); //no evidence of name property here

  if("name" in this){
    console.log("Name found"); //this is always the output
  } else {
    console.log("Name not found");
  }
  next();
});
```

The above code is for testing. Using either of the JSON objects above, the output is always "Name found" even though the object doesn't have a `name` property when I output to the console. Is this because the model has a `name` property?

Comment: Would you write down `UserSchema`? and what do you mean by `//no evidence of name property here`, what is already logged?

Comment: I've added it now

Comment: I mean that when I see the user object in the terminal, there is no property for `name` when using the JSON without `name`. The problem is that `"name" in this` still says it exists???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the user object in the terminal and there is no property for `name` because the posted json might not have a name field as you mentioned, so you may do your logic/condition just when the `name` property is existed as follow:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.name !== undefined) {
    if (this.name.length <= 6) {
      // throw error or whatever
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: But why is the `name` property always present? That's my question really

Comment: The answer to your question, is YES it's because the model has a `name` property, so you don't need to check if the key existed or not rather check the value itself, if passed returns the string, if not returns `undefined` and that makes sense.

Comment: So how do I distinguish between an empty value for user and when it's not included as a property at all? `if(this.name)` will produce false for both

Comment: I edited my answer above. `if (this.name !== undefined)`
Not provided at all: returns false,
Empty value: returns true.